# Angular ng-bind-html issue with emoji plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, emoji

I am using an angular emoji plugin that requires `ng-bind-html`. I am using this emoji plugin for creating messages, however I don't want it so that html code such as `<h2>hello</h2>` can be compiled but the ng-bind-html is mandatory to use the emoji plugin. Any suggestions/ways I can get around this so that posts will include emojis but not html code that gets compiled? Thanks

```js
angular.module("app", ["dbaq.emoji","ngSanitize"]).controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Animals: :dog: :cat: :snake: People: :smile: :confused: :angry: Places: :house: :school: :hotel: :poop:";
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="emoji.min.css">
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="emoji.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <div ng-bind-html="message | emoji"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

emoji plugin --> https://github.com/dbaq/angular-emoji-filter-hd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my simple solution:
1. Create file html like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="emoji.min.css">
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="emoji.min.js"></script><script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

    <textarea ng-model="message"></textarea><div ng-bind-html="message | emoji"></div>
</body>
```

Notes:
I embed file js called angular-sanitize.js. Copy [here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.0/angular-sanitize.js) and save as angular-sanitize.js. Then other files 'emoji.min.css, angular.js & emoji.min.js' exists on your app. Please mind your path too.

2.Create js file called script.js like this:

```
angular.module("app", ["emoji","ngSanitize"]).controller("AppCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.message = "Animals: :dog: :cat: :snake: People: :smile: :confused: :angry: Places: :house: :school: :hotel: :poop:";}]);
```

3.Run it.

Comment: hi, the plugin works for me. But if i dont want html code to run if I use an input field and bind that to the view. for example if i type <h2>hi</h2> it will make the font bigger. Is there a way around using this emoji plugin without html code compiling for my custom input

Comment: Add tag input/textarea with ng-model='message' like i do above (with textarea). i have edited my code..